# Google Cloud Storage bucket copy

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have two buckets in GCS. Each bucket has a table. 
I want to copy the buckets' content into Hadoop using Java SPARK. Is it possible via GCS Hadoop connector?

GCS pricing relays on the number of operations and their class (A or B), how can I estimate the number of operations needed? For example, is the number of operations to copy the content of a table equal to the number of fields (number of columns * number of lines) or is there another calculation method?

Comment: Operations is dependent on the number of executors that Spark starts up and number of files that get written. If you compress the output, there's less files, but same content

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007
I will have two tables one in each bucket and i'm only using GCS as a temporary buffer to copy the tables into our hadoop system.